# Is ORDER BY supposed to positively affect cursor performance and why?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor

I have a script that looks like this (`Id1` and `Id2` compose the table primiary key)

```
DECLARE @Id1 AS int,
        @Id2 AS smallint;

DECLARE c CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT Id1, Id2 FROM dbo.someTable ORDER BY Id1, Id2
OPEN c
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @Id1, @Id2
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            --Do stuff that do not depend on row order (getting random values and updating some of the fields)
            FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @Id1, @Id2
        END   
CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c
```

With the `ORDER BY Id1, Id2` clause it runs much faster than without it.

I expected that ordering the records would result some time waste, not time gain.

I have other similar scripts on other tables that gain less speed from similar `ORDER BY` clause.

So I'm wondering why I this `ORDER BY` clause can speed up a cursor, yet not all cursors.

Comment: Have you had a look at the execution plans? Can you post them?

Comment: If you are concerned about performance the best thing would be to get rid of the cursor. From the snippet of code posted and the description that you are updating each row you don't need a cursor. All it is doing is slowing this down so you can update RBAR (row by agonizing row). Show us the logic and we can show how to do it set based.

Comment: I know cursor have bad a reputation, but I need to do various things on each field... some need randoms value, some need similar random values than other fields, some random values need to be calculated, some other need to be fetched from a temporary table ... I posted a question on StackOverflow on the best way to do this, I got suggestions of things to try with expensive JOINs in "WITH" statements, results were all inaccurate or incomplete, yet I compared performances and the cursor was faster that case.

Comment: Just randomly updating random columns with random values sounds a little odd to me unless maybe it changing values from a production environment in a test/dev environment to protect the real data. There are other ways you can do this kind of thing.

Comment: We can't really answer your question about why this cursor would be faster once you sort the rows without knowing what it is doing inside and the table structures, indexes and, and ....

Comment: Yes, the purpose is data obfuscation. What other ways exist?

Comment: And my question is not about that specific query, but about some reasons why if would happen.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you are doing with the data. If you are inserting into a table you would want to do so in a certain order so as not to fragment the indexes.

Comment: I'd actually updating.